# How to disable active date hyperlink in calender at the next month?

Tags: php, date, hyperlink

How to disable active hyperlinks if month is changed?

As you can see at this [DEMO](http://bandymas.mooo.com), it shows, that 14th and 20th dates are active. When i am pressing button "Next" or "Previous" active links still is active.

**What i want to do:**

I want that active links will be disabled if month is different and has other active dates?

**Code:**

```
<?php

$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");

$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];

$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;

if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
$prev_month = 12;
$prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}

if ($next_month == 13 ) {
$next_month = 1;
$next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>">Previous</a>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>">Next</a><br/>

<?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?><br/>

<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";

$day = $i - $startday + 1;

if($i < $startday) {
    echo "<td></td>";
} elseif( ($day === 14) && ($thismonth !== 5) ) {
    echo "<a href='http://google.com/' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px; background:black; color:white;'>". $day . "</a>";
}
elseif( $day === 20) {
    echo "<a href='http://yahoo.com/' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px; background:black; color:white;'>". $day . "</a>";
}
else {
    echo "<a href='#' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px; color:black;'>". $day . "</a>";
}
if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

At elseif line **$thismonth** and **$cMonth** does not work.. i am trying to do this couple of ours, but with no success...

Thank to all of you, for any answers!

Comment: Do you mean different from current month and year or just *June, 2014*

Comment: Example: March has 14th and 20th active dates. If i am clicking "Next" button, than April also has 14th and 20th active dates. Active March dates should be disabled on other months, because other months should have other active dates :/ i dont know how to say it right :/

Comment: OK, I think I got it, now tell me how do you detect the active dates of each months? I mean how do you get the active date for each month?

Comment: If i understand what u are asking, than with elseif function: `elseif( ($day === 14) && ($thismonth !== 5) ) {
    echo "<a href='http://google.com/' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px; background:black; color:white;'>". $day . "</a>";
}` I am sitting on this maybe 3-4 ours..

Comment: No I mean which variable contains each month's active dates, then you can use it in your `if elseif`, and I will provide you a solution that you can use it

Comment: I really dont know, because i am newbie at php, and i found this script at internet. Let me try to guess: $cMonth ? i know that probably you are laughing, but.. well..i need to do this.. :/

Answer (score 0):

OK, base on what you provide if we assume that `$month_active_days` is an array which contains the active days in a specific month you need to change your `if` clause to this

```
$month_active_days = array(5, 20); // These are the active days in March for example but you need to have your own process to get the active days in each month like a sql query

...
if($i < $startday) {
   echo "<td></td>";
} elseif( in_array($day, $month_active_days) ) {
   // Do your stuff base on the $day value to show for example a specific link
}
else {
   echo "<a href='#' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px; color:black;'>". $day . "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. still when i am clicking "Next" button, all active March dates shows in the next and the next and the next... months. In elseif function, i included `echo "<a href='http://google.com/' style='float:left; margin:0px 5px; color:white; background:black;'>". $day . "</a>";` and now 5th and 20th days has 1 unique link, but not 2 different links :/ this code drives me to despair... :/